# VBA paste msoChart into Powerpoint 2010

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I am trying to paste an msoChart object with embedded data from the clipboard into PowerPoint 2010 using VBA. (chart created in Excel 2010).

The only examples that I can find involve either linking the Chart to an Excel file or creating a msoEmbeddedOLEObject.

If I manually paste in PowerPoint 2010 I get a paste option to "Embed Workbook". However it is not available within manual "Paste Special".

So it would seem that something in addition to pasting the chart is needed. But I am unsure what that is or how to go about it.

What I have tried is

```
Sub PasteExample()
Dim Sld As Slide
Dim Shp As ShapeRange

    Set Sld = ActiveWindow.View.Slide
    
    '# This pastes clipboard content as a linked chart
    Set Shp = Sld.Shapes.Paste
End Sub

Sub PasteExample2()
Dim Sld As Slide
Dim Shp As ShapeRange

    Set Sld = ActiveWindow.View.Slide

    '# This option does not work, object is still linked
    'Set Shp = Sld.Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPasteDefault, Link:=msoFalse)

    '# This option does not work, object is still linked
    'Set Shp = Sld.Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPasteShape, Link:=msoFalse)
    
    '# I'm not after OLEObjects
    'Set Shp = Sld.Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPasteOLEObject, Link:=msoFalse)
End Sub
```

Many thanks if you can shed some light.

Answer (score 0):

We don't see what you are copying and how, plz join code if problem not solved

Here are the members of PpPasteDataType that you can use with PasteSpecial in PowerPoint :

[image: members of PpPasteDataType]
Usually, I use that code as a base, it should help you :

```
Sub Export_to_Ppt()
'
Dim Ppt As PowerPoint.Application, _
    Pres As PowerPoint.Presentation

Set Ppt = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
Set Pres = Ppt.Presentations.Open("I:\Template DTC.potx")

Ppt.Visible = True

Sheets("Graph1").ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy

Pres.Slides.Add Index:=Pres.Slides.Count + 1, Layout:=ppLayoutTitleOnly
'Pres.Slides(Pres.Slides.Count).Shapes.Paste
Pres.Slides(Pres.Slides.Count).Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteEnhancedMetafile, Link:=False

Pres.Slides(Pres.Slides.Count).Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Chart Title"


Pres.SaveAs _
    Filename:="I:\TestNaz.ppt", _
    FileFormat:=ppSaveAsOpenXMLPresentation

Set Ppt = Nothing
Set Pres = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: The user will create a chart (any Excel chart) copying it manualy to the clipboard (Crtl + C). I'm after a Powerpoint solution that will insert the chart from the clipboard and Embedd the data, but not an EmbeddedOLEObject and not a linked chart.

Comment: Ok so you should use this : `Pres.Slides(Pres.Slides.Count).Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteEnhancedMetafile, Link:=False`

Comment: That will just insert a picture. I am greatful that your trying, but it seem that you have not read the question above the code i posted.

Comment: Ok, I see your exact problem now, but it seems that the 2 properties in Powerpoint Chart class that could help you `DataTable` and `ChartData` are both in Read-Only...

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your example with PowerPoint 2013. I wasn't able to reproduce the behaviour that you describe.

*Pre-Condition: I copied an Excel 2013 chart to the Clipboard (just the chart, not the whole worksheet or anything else).*

Invoking either `Sld.Shapes.Paste` or `Sld.Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPasteDefault,Link:=msoFalse)` will insert an msoChart into Powerpoint:

```
Set shp = Sld.Shapes.Paste
MsgBox shp.Type ' returns 3 that is msoChart

Set shp = Sld.Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPasteDefault, Link:=msoFalse)
MsgBox shp.Type 'returns 3 that is msoChart
```

Those charts are properly formatted in the current PowerPoint style and I can right-click them to edit the data.

Especially, they are embedded, not linked.

---

For comparison I also tried:

```
Set shp = Sld.Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPasteOLEObject, Link:=msoFalse)
MsgBox shp.Type ' returns 7 that is msoEmbeddedOLEObject 

Set shp = Sld.Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPasteOLEObject, Link:=msoTrue)
MsgBox shp.Type ' returns 10 that is msoLinkedOLEObject 

Set shp = Sld.Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPasteDefault, Link:=msoTrue)
MsgBox shp.Type 'returns 10 that is msoLinkedOLEObject
```

When I right-click those in Powerpoint, then there is are menu entries to manipulate the “Worksheed Object” respectively the “Linked Worksheed Object”.

So either I misunderstand what you mean by "linked", or there is a bug in PP 2010, or you are having something different in your clipboard.

Comment: Sounds like there have been some improvements/bug fixes in Powerpoint 2013. 
Unfortunately I have no way at the moment to verfy this.

Answer (score 0):

I did come upon a solution on another form.
Once the chart is in the clipboard.

Execute the following line in PowerPoint 2010

```
    Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "PasteExcelChartDestinationTheme"
```

It gave me just what I was after.